# Jmeter | PerformanceTesting | Cookie Manager Issue

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded using jmeter and enhanced the script but facing a redirected response as below:

Object moved

### Object moved to [here](/Gorhn/Bypass/WebPortal/v2020_testing2_2020_Web/Login.aspx).

I tried using Cookie manager and also correlated viewstate and viewgenerator still facing a object moved error

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with "Redirect automatically" and/or "Follow redirects" checkboxes in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

the idea is to [make JMeter to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) so cross-check the requests JMeter is making with the requests from the "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

As the last resort you should be able to extract the [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) URL from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and configure the next HTTP Request sampler to hit this URL.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for the hep. Now that my redirected response has cleared.
But I do face an error while the expected response varies with the actual response. 
I have checked the header files and other parameters; everything is going as expected in the request but i'm getting a varied response when comparing with the chrome dev tools. 
I'm not sure anything i'm missing in this